# Windows adhoc mesh network

Tags: windows, wifi, adhoc, mesh-network

I have googled the heck out of this topic, but I still need help.  There are similar questions on stackoverflow, but none match exact (nor do they have good answers).

I want to write a program (if it doesn't already exist and if it is possible) that allows Windows 7+ users to configure an ad-hoc mesh network using a single WiFi adapter and then somehow allows connectivity similar to normal internet connectivity for each node.  Bonus is if devices like phones do not need extra software, but can connect to one or more mesh nodes as if it were a standard access point.

I don't know how to do this, but I think:

1. A single wireless card can be configured to operate in adhoc mode programmatically using the Windows Wireless-ADHOC API
2. Ad hoc mode usually excludes infrastucture mode unless the adapter's driver supports it, so connection from a node to the real internet would need a second adapter.
3. Our program would have/need exclusive control of the WiFi adapter.
4. The mesh aspect is achieved independently of the adhoc connectivity by a routing protocol such as Babel.
5. Internet would have to be provided through some new virtual adapter that is created by our program.  (What role does this new adapter play that makes it the adapter that any network aware program should choose to consult for internet access?)
6. If a real internet connection is available on a node, this would be shared by that node to other nodes on the mesh through the Babel implementation
7. Whether or not internet is available from any node, not sure what services could be hosted within the mesh itself.  How is resource/domain name resolution provided?
8. If the current node has internet, any requests to internet resources would go directly through it and any resources within the mesh would go through Babel.  If direct internet is lost by that node, all traffic would go through Babel.  Does this need to be programmed for or does the windows network stack know how to deal with this, assuming our program is written correctly?
9. Since this is Windows 7+, IPv6 is a legitimate choice for addressing nodes in the mesh, however, not all internet connectivity is expected to support IPv6.  Some might.  How do we define the internet segment from the mesh segment?
10. The mesh can be arbitrarily large and Babel and the other components would be able to handle it with good bandwidth, low memory usage, and optimal path convergence.

It's pretty clear that I don't have the background to actually complete this project, but I'd like to understand the outline of a solution.  Can you comment on what is right about the outline, what is missing/wrong?  What concepts are unnecessary or obsolete because of the advent of newer technologies?

How simple could a node be to operate?  How secure can each node be from other nodes attacking them?  Poisoning network traffic & routing?

I've read about projects that attempt similar goals for Linux, but nothing for current for Windows.  Some discussions of vehicular and emergency responders, but this is different.  My interest is, piqued by Hurricane Sandy, in connectivity for popular residential operating systems in situations of widespread urban connectivity outages.  When power and communication systems for many are unavailable, the mesh can help.

Almost all mesh participants will not have configured their nodes in advance.  Instead, they might look for other's wireless networks when theirs are down and find the SSID "Free Emergency Mesh WiFi" and connect.  As with hotspots, they would be presented with a proxied login page that explains the project and offers an install link if they want to participate.  If not, they can still connect to the mesh "access point" as a client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're basically asking to put a single WiFi radio into three separate modes at the same time. In order for the node to talk to other nodes it needs to be in Ad-Hoc mode. In order to talk to the access point (AP) for Internet access it needs to be in Infrastructure mode. In order for mobile phones to connect, well most of them don't support Ad-Hoc networks so you'll need to put your nodes into Master mode as well (make them appear as normal access points). So on a single WiFi card you're trying to juggle three different modes of operation. In theory if the card and drivers you have support raw frame injection then you might be able to emulate the WiFi and networking stacks in your application and juggle all three modes on a single card, but I have a feeling that would lead to a very high rate of collisions, lost frames, high latency, and all the extra CPU cycles would burn through your battery if you're running this on a laptop.

Is it possible? Sure. Is it a practical idea? Not really. You're better off extending the laptop with small/cheap WiFi adapters like the ASUS USB-N10. The extra adapters can handle the extra modes, do the processing in firmware and kernel-space where it's faster and more efficient, and allow you to run each layer of the network on a separate channel for MUCH higher throughput.

Comment: (Point 2 allows for the requirement of a second, possibly hard-wired, adapter for the internet connection).

Comment: Good insights.  Ok, but would there be user adoption value in supporting those modes in raw mode if only one adapter is available, but advertising that - "hey, for next time, a second and even third adapter would improve performance"?

Comment: I really don't think so. Mesh networking already has a pretty weak reputation so coming out with a solution that is slow and finicky would reinforce the negative stereotypes for people and they wouldn't bother trying out other configurations. They'll just say, "See, I knew mesh networking could never work!"

Having first-hand experience in trying to combat the myths and sell mesh networking as a viable solution, my advice is don't bother offering anything less than the best. Critics will take laziest path to reviewing your project and declare every shortcoming as proof that it can never work.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know if 802.11s will do everything I'm talking about?  And is the 's' a hardware implementation like 'a' 'b' 'g' and 'n' need to be or will it be a separate layer done in software?

Comment: ... with further research, it seems to me that 802.11s MAP mode is the right choice and that the OPEN80211S suggests that the implementation can be done in software on existing hardware.  You seem to know a lot about this topic.  Do wireless adapters do processing on the adapter itself or is the CPU the one doing that work?  Does this OPEN80211S project do it on the CPU by putting the adapter in raw mode, as you mentioned, or is it more like a Shader program of a graphics card, where the instructions are given to the adapter to carry out on its own?